Let it die or improve it? What's the task of the "active" community on potentially good questions?
A couple of days ago this question appeared on this SE.
In a few hours the question got 4 downvotes and its dilemma was buried forever in the limbo of the wannabe questions.
Even if it wasn't perfect, I saw a potentially good question in it and therefore, guided by the discussion beneath it, I simplified it, upvoted it and gave it back to the community.
Now it looks like this and after the edit it went from -4 to +3 (so, +7 in total) and got 5 answers that apparently pleased the OP. With more than 300 views it's also one of the most visited answers of the past few days... it wasn't that bad after all.
So far so good. But then I thought if this was actually the correct thing to do:

should I have left the answer die (since the OP wasn't clearly able to improve it by him/herself and since this was the wish of the community);
OR should the "active" community (myself included) have left comments beneath it ( possibly without downvotes) and then improved the answer according to those comments (as I did)?

What's the task of the community in these cases: let it die or give a chance?

There's a few things to unpack here.
Over the years, we have had a number of users who I will term "The persistently curious". They all follow a similar pattern:

A couple of reasonable questions, which are usually a bit naive but garner upvotes and decent answers.

A deluge of questions, some OK, others terrible. They start to get the odd downvote, probably correctly.

A continued avalanche of questions, and whether good or bad, they get downvoted to hell not because of bad content but because of the attached name having worn out peoples good will. This is not OK, but it's somewhat just human nature.


I believe the question you linked was this user somewhere between 2. and 3.

Should you have fixed this? Not necessarily, you would have been well within your right of course to just move on. But by fixing it you have improved the community, and ultimately that is what these sites are supposed to be. So good on you for fixing it, and for returning it to a state where it was answerable and useful. I thank you, and I'm sure the community would too!

Yeah, and I would thank @sophit a lot since it's my post. However, can you please explain why I fall into somewhere between 2 and 3? Also, what (posts) can I improve to pull myself out of that scenario (2 and/or 3, because both sounds pretty bad). I'll appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

@AircraftEnthusiast007 You should never, ever say "thanks in advance" on SE. Or use lots of other "noise" phrases.
